# Access violation writing location C++ while using SDL2.0

Tags: c++

Here is some of my code for the MainCharacter and NPC's (I know that the code is sloppy)

When i try to check if a quest is active
void CMainCharacter::MissionSets() {

```
using namespace std;

if (npc->StoryLineMission = npc->NoMission)
{
    if (npc->StoryLineMission = npc->LearningTheTruth) {
        cout << "hello" << endl;

    }
}
```

}

i have storylinemission defined
StoryLineMission = NoMission;

here is all of the quests
oid CNPC::UpdateQuest() {

```
if (QuestMission == NoQuest) {

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
        {
            std::cout << "Quests have been activated" << std::endl;
            QuestMission = Quest;
        }
    }
}
if (QuestMission == Quest) {

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q) {
            QuestMission = QuestActive;
            std::cout << "Quest/Mission has been delivered to you" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

if (QuestMission == QuestActive)
{
    if (StoryLineMission == NoMission) {
        StoryLineMission = LearningTheTruth;
    }
    else if (StoryLineMission == LearningTheTruthCompleted) {
        StoryLineMission = MeetingOldFriends;
    }
    else if (StoryLineMission == MeetingOldFriendsCompleted) {
        StoryLineMission = HelpingFriends;
    }
    else if (StoryLineMission == HelpingFriendsCompleted) {
        StoryLineMission = TheChasing;
    }
    else if (StoryLineMission == TheChasingCompleted) {
        StoryLineMission = TheReturn;
    }
}
if (StoryLineMission == LearningTheTruth)
{
    LearningTheTruthArrowDown1->Draw();
    LearningTheTruthArrowRight1->Draw();
    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            LearningTheTruthPart1->Draw();
            LearningTheTruthPart2->Draw();
            LearningTheTruthPart3->Draw();
            LearningTheTruthPart4->Draw();
        }
    }

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c) {
            QuestMission = LearningTheTruthQuestCompleted;
            StoryLineMission = LearningTheTruthCompleted;
            QuestType = LearningTheTruthQuestCompleted;
        }
    }

}

if (StoryLineMission == MeetingOldFriends) {

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            MeetingOldFriendsPart1->Draw();
            MeetingOldFriendsPart2->Draw();
        }
    }

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c) {
            QuestMission = MeetingOldFriendsQuestCompleted;
            StoryLineMission = MeetingOldFriendsCompleted;
            QuestType = MeetingOldFriendsQuestCompleted;
        }
    }
}

if (StoryLineMission == HelpingFriends) {

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {

        }
    }

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c) {
            QuestMission = HelpingFriendsQuestCompleted;
            StoryLineMission = HelpingFriendsCompleted;
            QuestType = HelpingFriendsQuestCompleted;
        }
    }
}

if (StoryLineMission == TheChasing) {
    std::cout << "The Chasing" << std::endl;

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {

        }
    }

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c) {
            QuestMission = TheChasingQuestCompleted;
            StoryLineMission = TheChasingCompleted;
            QuestType = TheChasingQuestCompleted;
        }
    }
}

if (StoryLineMission == TheReturn) {
    std::cout << "Welcome Home" << std::endl;

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {

        }
    }

    if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        if (csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c) {
            QuestMission = TheReturnQuestCompleted;
            StoryLineMission = TheReturnCompleted;
            QuestType = TheReturnQuestCompleted;
        }
    }
}

if (QuestMission == LearningTheTruthQuestCompleted) {
    std::cout << "LearningTheTruth has been succesfully completed" << std::endl;
    StoryLineMission = LearningTheTruthCompleted;
    QuestMission = Quest;
}

if (QuestMission == MeetingOldFriendsQuestCompleted) {
    std::cout << "Meeting Old Friends has been succesfully completed" << std::endl;
    StoryLineMission = MeetingOldFriendsCompleted;
    QuestMission = Quest;
}

if (QuestMission == HelpingFriendsQuestCompleted) {
    std::cout << "HelpingFriends quest has been succesfully completed" << std::endl;

    StoryLineMission = HelpingFriendsCompleted;
    QuestMission = Quest;
}
if (QuestMission == TheChasingQuestCompleted) {
    std::cout << "The Chasing has been completed" << std::endl;

    StoryLineMission = TheChasingCompleted;
    QuestMission = Quest;
}

if (QuestMission == TheReturnQuestCompleted) {
    std::cout << "The Return has been completed" << std::endl;

    StoryLineMission = TheReturnCompleted;
    QuestMission = QuestsDone;
}

if (QuestMission == QuestsDone) {
//  AllQuestsDone->Draw();
}

if (QuestType == LearningTheTruthQuestCompleted) {
    if (StoryLineMission == LearningTheTruthCompleted) {
        SLearningTheTruthCompleted->Draw();
    }
}

if (QuestType == MeetingOldFriendsQuestCompleted) {
    if (StoryLineMission == MeetingOldFriendsCompleted) {
        SMeetingOldFriendsCompleted->Draw();
    }
}

if (QuestType == HelpingFriendsQuestCompleted) {
    if (StoryLineMission == HelpingFriendsCompleted) {
        SHelpingFriendsCompleted->Draw();
    }
}

if (QuestType == TheChasingQuestCompleted) {
    if (StoryLineMission == TheChasingCompleted) {
        STheChasingCompleted->Draw();
    }
}

if (QuestType == TheReturnQuestCompleted) {
    if (StoryLineMission == TheReturnCompleted) {
        STheReturnCompleted->Draw();
        //AllQuestsDone->Draw();
    }
}
```

}

and everytime i try to run it i get an access violation writing location and i cant seem to get this to work.

I'm calling the mission sets function in a different class

void CMain::GameLoop(void)
{

```
while (!quit && csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->type != SDL_QUIT)
{
    csdl_setup->Begin();

    //Tiles
    Forest->DrawBack();

    //NPC
    OrcNPC->Draw();
    OrcNPC->UpdateComputerNPC();

    //Players
    Josh->Draw();
    Josh->Update();

    Forest->DrawFront();
    Forest->Update();

    //Quests
    OrcNPC->UpdateQuest();
    OrcNPC->DeleteQuest();
    OrcNPC->UpdateAnimation();

    Josh->MissionSets();

    csdl_setup->End();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that just a typo in **if** statements? Change = to ==

```
if (npc->StoryLineMission == npc->NoMission)
{
    if (npc->StoryLineMission == npc->LearningTheTruth) {
        cout << "hello" << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: nvm I fixed the access violation reading location error. I didn't have npc defined as anything in my MainCharacter class. Derp